# React-TypeScript-DatePicker highlight dates from REST API

Tags: typescript, rest, react-datepicker

I want to highlight dates that i receive from REST API.

When is i call this:
`` fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/tickets/dates`) ``

I can siis that i get the response:

```
["2020-07-11T00:00:00", "2020-05-19T00:00:00", "2020-07-16T00:00:00", "2020-09-20T00:00:00",…]
0: "2020-07-11T00:00:00"
1: "2020-05-19T00:00:00"
2: "2020-07-16T00:00:00"
3: "2020-09-20T00:00:00"
4: "2020-05-30T00:00:00
```

Now im stuck with how to pass the dates to an array and use them with datepicker highlightDates property.

I've tried different approaches, but cant find a solution.

This is my code right now:

```
state = {
        startDate: new Date(),
        dates: []
      };

public componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/tickets/dates`).then(results => results.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({
            dates: json
        })
    });
    console.log(this.state.dates)
}    

<DatePicker  
       locale="et" 
       selected={this.state.startDate} 
       onChange={this.handleChange} 
       highlightDates={[new Date(this.state.dates[0])]}
       inline/>
```

In DatePicker i would like to pass the whole array of dates.

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with spread operator as follows:

```
<DatePicker  
       locale="et" 
       selected={this.state.startDate} 
       onChange={this.handleChange} 
       highlightDates={[...this.state.dates]}
       inline/>
```